# RSS to iCal Script/service?

Tags: php, rss

How might I convert an RSS feed of events to an ical format so that I can import into Google Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to do that Kind of thing, I would probably use something like :

- [`Zend_Feed_Reader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html) to read the RSS feed
- and the ZF classes that allow to create google-calendar events -- see [Using Google Calendar](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html)

The idea being that these classes should work fine, are well-tested and all that -- which means less time spent re-inventing the wheel and debugging : basically, the only thing you'd have to do is write a couple of lines of *glue* to :

- get the data from the first class
- and pass it to the second one

And, in both cases, the examples given in the manual should help quite a lot.